# Scala: flatten mixed set of sets (or lists or arrays)

Tags: scala

I have a Set which incorporates a combination of strings, and subSets of strings, like so:

```
val s = Set(brand1-_test, Set(brand-one, brand_one, brandone), brands-two, brandthree1, Set(brand-three2, brand_three2, brandthree2))
```

How do I flatten this so that I have one flat set of strings? `s.flatten` doesn't work with the following error:

```
error: No implicit view available from Object => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]
```

Neither does flatMap. What am I missing here? The Set could just as easily incorporate a subLists or subArrays (they are the result of a previous function), if that makes a difference.

Comment: You have a `Set[Any]`. The compiler doesn't know how to flatten that.

Comment: But the items in each set are all the same (strings) - does that not make a difference? Is there any way to flatten this?

Comment: They are not the same. Some elements are strings and some are sets.

Comment: oooo, OK, go it - thanks for the clarification.

Comment: the solution from @Dima deals with this very nicely!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 s.flatMap { case x:Iterable[_] => x; case y => Seq(y) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting it in a REPL:

```
scala> val s = Set("s1", Set("s2", "s3"))
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Object] = Set(s1, Set(s2, s3))
```

since you are providing two types (Set and String) then scala infers a type which covers both (Object in this case, but probably Any or AnyRef in most cases) which is not a collection and therefore cannot be flattened.